# How can I represent a weighted many-to-many relationship in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

At the moment we have a many-to-many relationship between our entities, something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Episode {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "episode_category",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "episode_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }
    )
    private List<Category> categories;

}
```

However, in some circumstances, this relationship is weighted using a probability (`double` between `0.0` and `1.0`).

What would the best way to represent this?

On first thought, I imagined a Map relationship, something like:

```
@Entity
public class Episode {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            ?
    )
    private Map<Category, Double> weightedCategories;

}
```

Is this possible in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a [@MapKeyJoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) annotation to do that. There is an example of what you want to do in the javadoc:

```
public class VideoStore {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="INVENTORY",
                     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STORE"))
    @Column(name="COPIES_IN_STOCK")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="MOVIE", referencedColumnName="ID")
    Map<Movie, Integer> videoInventory;
```